# How to calculate lattitude and longitude from x-y coordinates for geotagged images

Tags: reactjs, image, coordinates, pixel, latitude-longitude

In my react application, I have geotagged images with the center latitude-longitude, height and width.
When clicked on the image I'm getting x-y co-ordinates(pixels of image) where clicked.

**I want to calculate the possible lat-lon co-ordinates from center lat-lon and x,y pixels of image.**

Is there any way to do this  ? Someone please help .

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is there as well a "scale" on the image ? "X amount of pixel = distance"

Comment: Actually this needs to be calculated as well

Comment: I am not sure with only the available information you can actually calculate the scale, but I might be missing something here.

Since you only have "lat,lon" of the image
width & height of image ( in px )
You need the info of 1px = ( x distance), this could be inputed by user or something you already know, but to calculate that you would need another "lat,lon" on the image ( if you had that we wouldn't need the scale in theory )

Comment: I only have one lat-lon on the image. And I think 1 pixel = 1 cm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments above, if you have a scale of 1 pixel = 1cm ( which seems to be very small, if you have a 4000x2100px image, means you are about 40meters x 21meters )

To then calculate the lat-lon on click or hover of the x-y position of the cursor:

```
const R = 6378160; // Earth Radius in meters
const scale = 0.01; ( in meters 1cm = 0.01m per pixel )
const midX = imageWidth / 2;
const midY = imageHeight / 2;

const dX = x - midX; // Difference for x position in pixel;
const dY = y - midY; // Difference for y position in pixel;

// Get the difference in meters
const dXScaled = dX * scale;
const dYScaled = dY * scale;

// Convert the difference in latitude, longitude
const dLat = ( dXScaled / R ) * Math.PI / 180;
const dLon = ( dYScaled / (R*Cos(Math.PI *lat/180))) * Math.PI / 180;

// Return new position
return {
  lon: lon + dLon,
  lat: lat + dLat,
}
```

You can verify the above answer with this https://scienceweb.whoi.edu/marine/ndsf/cgi-bin/NDSFutility.cgi?form=0&from=XY&to=LatLon ( if something is incorrect above, let me know I'll correct )

Comment: Thank you so much !! I'm getting the output as expected :) But please clarify this : midY should calculate from the imageHeight and 1cm = 0.01 m  so scale should be 0.01 , right ?

Comment: Correct sorry ! Updating to the following